# How to set variable from selectOneMenu in JSF

Tags: jsf, selectonemenu

Here is what I have

```
<h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{userBean.chosen_Cinema}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Cinemas Available" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Stafford" itemLabel="Stafford" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Stoke" itemLabel="Stoke" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="Hastings" itemLabel="Hastings" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
```

My backing bean code is

```
public class UserBean
{
        private String Chosen_Cinema;

        public void setChosen_Cinema(String Cinema)
        {
            Chosen_Cinema = Cinema;
        }                
        public String getChosen_Cinema()
        {
            return Chosen_Cinema;
        }
}
```

I set a breakpoint on the set method but it never triggers.

Comment: Where are you submitting the form..??

Comment: <h:form>
         <h:commandButton value="submit" type="submit" action="#{userBean.confirmbooking}" />     
        </h:form>




public String confirmbooking()
            {  
            return "confirmbooking";  
            }
@BalusC

Comment: So, the submit button is in a different form than the input?

Comment: So, you expected that all other forms in the same HTML document are also submitted when you submit one form? Which HTML tutorial/book/resource exactly gave you this misinformation?